# Passing MainWindow instance to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, window, viewmodel

In my WPF application I need to send do something with my MainWindow on the ViewModel. So my idea was to set `this.DataContext = new ViewModel (this)` in code-behind, and then in the constructor of the view-model I could just use the 'this' parameter that I had sent as the Window instance:

```
public ViewModel(Window Wndw){/../}
```

Now what I need to do is access a 'MainGrid' element that is inside my window:

```
<Window bunch
        of
        stuff>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when I try something like:

```
Grid MGrid = Wndw.FindName("MainGrid") as Grid
```

I don't get any errors but it is always null, so I keep getting Null Reference Exception when I try to do anything with MGrid.

On the other hand, the **Wndw is not null**, I tested that. And also, passing MainGrid instead of the whole Window is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't do that. Never pass that window to view model.   Then there is no use in following MVVM pattern.

Comment: I don't strictly follow the MVVM pattern

Comment: Then write the code simply in Window.xaml.cs than passing it to viewmodel. This seems to be a useless practice. Using MVVM you could access the window in view model. Don't inject it to view model constructor like this.

Answer (score 1):

why use the FindName method ? You could do this :

```
Grid MGrid = Wndw.MainGrid;
```

And instead of giving the window in your view model params, you could do this :

```
// if the window you want is your main window
CustomWindow the_window = (CustomWindow )App.Current.MainWindow;

// if it's a secondary window
CustomWindow the_window = (CustomWindow )Window.GetWindow(your_view_model_object);
// for this, you have to check if the control is already loaded.
```

Comment: What is 'App' in your context?

Comment: Your window has no definition of MainGrid because you are casting it to the Window class. If your window class is CustomWindow you have to keep the right cast: public ViewModel(CustomWindow  Wndw){/../}

Comment: App is the default Application class of your project. It is this class which create your main window.

Comment: I tried passing the argument as public ViewModel(MainWindow Wndw){}

Now Wndw.MainGrid does compile but still returns null

Comment: Do you manipulate the MainGrid elsewhere ? Cause there is no reason for it to be null

Comment: No, That's the only place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118783/discussion-between-aleksa-kojadinovic-and-kanax).